# See if a list of strings in df1[Keyword'] is found anywhere in a df2['Description'] and drop rows if df2 if no matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, *df1* and *df2*.

df1 contains a list of strings in a column called 'Keyword'. I'm trying to see if these strings are found within a second dataframe, df2['Description'] and drop the rows in df2 if they do not contain at least one of the strings from df1['Keyword']

```
df1                 df2
Keyword             Description   
Car                 I like driving my **car**      <- Keep
Dog                 No keywords here!              <- Drop Row
Elephant            Bart gets an **Elephant**      <- Keep
Bat                 No keywords in this sentence   <- Drop Row
```

**What I've tried:**

```
df2['Check'] = df1["Keyword"].isin(df2[Description"])
```

Everything elevates to FALSE, even when there is a match. The idea is to drop all rows which contain FALSE once the code was working.

Comment: do they have to be in the same rows in both dataframes? Or, can the keyword be in one row in one dataframe and in another row in the other dataframe

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
You can create a long string of unique values joined by `|`and use `str.contains` to search for those values and pass `case=False`:

```
df1['Check'] = df2['Description'].str.contains('|'.join(df1['Keyword'].unique()), case=False)
Out[1]: 
    Keyword  Check
0       Car   True
1       Dog  False
2  Elephant   True
3       Bat  False
```

**Solution 2:** You can use list comprehension to check if `any` values are in the column. Make sure to use `lower` to normalize the case, so that you get a match as python is case-sensitive::

```
df1['Check'] = (df1["Keyword"].apply(
                                     lambda x: any([True 
                                     for y in df2['Description'].str.casefold()
                                     if x.lower() in y])))
#str.casefold() is potentially more robust than str.lower() if text is not in English
df1
Out[2]: 
    Keyword  Check
0       Car   True
1       Dog  False
2  Elephant   True
3       Bat  False
```

From there, just do `df1[df1['Check']]`:

```
    Keyword    Check
0   Car         True
2   Elephant    True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lookup() function which returns label based indexing functions for DataFrame

```
def lookup(x, values):
    for value in values:
        if value.lower() in x.lower():
            return value
```

And then you can apply the function to df2
`df2['df2'] = df2['B'].apply(lambda x: lookup(x, df1['df2']))`

Comment: This is great thanks! Is there a way to pull out all of of the keyword matches into new columns using this method?

['Check 2'] and ['Check 3'] columns with the additional matches. Thanks!